# The YouTube iframe API serves streams at resolutions that will not playback over cellular connections

Tags: youtube-api

I hope that the YouTube API team will address the following issue.

YouTube has disabled the ability to request a specific size using the `setPlaybackQuality()` method.

If I am correct, the YouTube iframe API automatically determines the appropriate resolution / size to serve up (small, medium, large, hd720 etc) depending upon the pixel dimensions of the embedded player.

This is a huge problem over cellular networks.

AT&T, Verizon, TMobile and others have all begun to throttle video streams and / or disable playback all together in some cases for streams above 480p.

In our case, we are seeing 1.5 - 2 minutes of buffering before playback in the embedded YouTube player at widths above 360px.

In portrait mode this limit would at least be somewhat acceptable, but in full-screen landscape on mobile, the preferred method for watching video, YouTube changes the quality automatically and in most cases serves up HD720p which almost immediately becomes stuck in buffering mode over cellular connections.

We need the ability to request a specific resolution, and/or we need YouTube to serve up video at 480p over cellular connections.

Answer (score -1):

The `suggestedQuality` parameter of `player.setPlaybackQuality(suggestedQuality:String):Void` determines appropriate playback quality not only depending upon the pixel dimensions of the embedded player, but actually varies for different users, videos, systems and other playback conditions.

Setting the parameter value to `default` instructs YouTube to select the most appropriate playback quality.

> YouTube selects the appropriate playback quality. This setting effectively reverts the quality level to the default state and nullifies any previous efforts to set playback quality using the [`cueVideoById`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#cueVideoById), [`loadVideoById`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#loadVideoById) or `setPlaybackQuality` functions.

I assume this also takes mobile connections into consideration, but if you believe there is an issue on this API feature, you can contact YouTube [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803).

Comment: I could be mistaken, but i believe the `setPlaybackQuality()` method is now ignored. Regardless, i have tried using this method anyway, and still i am seeing the player attempt to load HD720p over cellular, and testing has shown that AT&T and Verizon are blocking and/or throttling video streams above 480p. In testing we loaded the same player over AT&T and TMobile. Over AT&T the video is throttled and will not play, while over TMobile, the video played without issue. I did create an issue for this as well at YouTube. Hoping for a response.